# Number of ways of taking `N` candies

Tags: algorithm, math, puzzle

I have a problem and I don't know how I can start to solve it. Do you know someone a formula, algorithm or type of problems like this?

I have only number `N`, `N` candies, and I need to count the number of ways of taking `N` candies, but except the first candy taken, the candy taken must be adjacent to one of previous candies taken before. For example if `N = 3` there are 4 ways of taking:

- Taking candy number 1 first; then candy 2, 3.
- Taking candy number 2 first; then 1, 3.
- Taking candy number 2 first; then 3, 1.
- Taking candy number 3 first; then candy 2, 1.

Comment: I nave only number `N`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics not about programming.  As I write the question and all the answers it has received so far are entirely, and rightly, code free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways for `n` candies is the sum of the `n-1`th row of [pascal's triangle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle).

Comment: Isn't it the `n`th row?  If you have 2 candies, you need 1+1 ways, for 3 candies you need 1+2+1 ways, etc...

Comment: @C8H10N4O2: Under the usual indexing, the row {1} is the 0th row, {1,1} is the first row, and {1,2,1} is the second row. So, the n-1st row is correct, the one summing to 2^(n-1).

Answer (score 2):

If you take candy k first, then there's choose(n-1, k-1) ways of choosing the rest (where choose(n, k) is the binomial coefficient nCk). That's because after the first, you either have to take the right-most unchosen candy to the left of k, or the left-most unchosen candy to the right of k, and there's (k-1) candies to the left of k.

Summing over k, gives you all possible ways taking into account the first choice: sum(k=1...n)choose(n-1, k-1).

Since choose(n-1, k-1) is the number of ways of choosing k-1 items from n-1 items, this sum is equal to the number of ways of choosing any number of items from n-1 items. That's 2^(n-1).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pattern:

```
number of candies
1   2   3   4
1   12  123 1234
    21  213 2134
        231 2314
        321 2341
            3214
            3241
            3421
            4321
1   2   4   8
total ways
```

Does this remind you of something?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we first take `i-th` candy. Then we have `i - 1` candies to the left and `N - i` to the right. Every next candy taken is the rightmost from the left part, or leftmost from the right part. Left and right parts are independent, so number of possible ways to take all candies are number of unique permutations of the sequence `LLLL....LLLRRR....RRR` where `i - 1` `L's` and `N - i` `R's`.

Total number of such permutations is:

```
SequenceLength!/(count(L)!*count(R)!) = (N - 1)!/((i - 1)! * (N - i)!)
```

Now, if we sum over all possible `i` values, we have:

[image: formula]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go through binomial coefficients.

There are 2^(n-1) sequences of Rs and Ls of length n-1. These are in bijection with the sequences of taking candies by writing down whether your next candy is on the right or left of the ones you have taken before. Any sequence of Rs and Ls uniquely determines the location of the first candy: If there are a Ls, then the first candy must be in position a+1.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation, probably more useful in theory:

Given a 1-indexed array `C` of candy marbles (1 for not yet taken and 0 for taken, all starting at 1) and a starting point `N`:

1. If `N` is negative, zero, or greater than the size of `C`, end without doing anything.
2. If `C[N]` is 0, end without doing anything.
3. If `C[N]` is 1, set it to 0, add 1 to the count of possible paths, then check `C[N-1]` and `C[N+1]` against this algorithm.

Simply repeat this algorithm for every valid index in `C`. Also, ensure each recursion has a copy of `C`, not the original `C`, but they all share the total number of paths.

Stepping through the first part of your example:

1. `C[1]` is 1, so we set it to 0, add 1, and check `C[0]` and `C[2]`.
2. 0 is 0, so we stop that recursion.
3. `C[2]` is 1, so we set it to 0 and check `C[1]` and `C[3]`.
4. `C[1]` is 0.
5. `C[3] is 1, so we set it to 0 and check`C[2]`and`C[4]`.
6. `C[2]` is 0.
7. 4 is greater than 3.

Repeat for `N=2` and `N=3`, and for longer arrays just loop.